# $scope.$digest() doesn't populate select2 drop down list

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-digest

I have 2 drop down lists using ui-select2

```
                        <label class="control-label" for="MakeSelect">Make </label>
                    <select class="form-control col-md-2" id="MakeSelect" name="make" ui-select2
                            ng-model="carDetails.make">
                        <option ng-if="!carDetails.make" value="">[SELECT]</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="make in makes" value="{{ make }}">{{ make}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <label class="control-label" for="ModelSelect">Model </label>
                <select class="form-control col-md-2" id="ModelSelect" name="make" ui-select2
                        ng-model="carDetails.model">
                    <option ng-repeat="model in models" value="{{ model }}">{{ make}}</option>
                </select>
```

After I choose a value in the drop down list "Makes" I am activating a watch that inside it I load the content of "Models" Dropdown lists.
Then, In order to refresh the drop down lists content in the GUI I call $scope.$digest() :

```
$scope.$watch('carDetails.make', function (make) {
    console.log('selected make is: ' + make);
    if (make == "") {
        return;
    }

    Parse.Cloud.run('getCarModels', {'Make': make}, {
        success: function (results) {
            $scope.parseModels = results.resultSet;
            $scope.models = results.distinctModels;
            $scope.$digest();
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error: Failed to load models");
            console.log(Parse.Error);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that **with** $digest the selected value of the first drop down list is becoming null and **without** it just doesn't refresh the view.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both pointing to the same scope model, carDetails.make.  So, of course, the first will become null, because the second drop down list sets carDetails.make to null.  Also, I don't think you need to use digest, although, you should be using $scope.$apply.  But, angularjs should run the digest anyway.

Comment: I uploaded an old version, but even after I fixed that it doesn't populate it. I edited my question, thanks.

Comment: hmm, the only other thing I can see is that in order for ng-model to work on a select, there has to be an option with value of "".  I don't think you're model dropdown list has a value for "".

Comment: Oh, and both selects have the same name="make" one should be make and the other model

Comment: I didn't understand your first comment, can you explain more?

Comment: I apologize,  AngularJs won't bind to a select html element unless it has an option with the value "".  So just add this to the model dropdown list.  <option ng-if="!carDetails.model" value="">[SELECT]</option>